# Laravel project doesn't start on subfolders

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, subdirectory

I have a problem, I wrote an application but it doesn't work on sub folder. I have to prepare my program to work in sub folders. For example:

127.0.0.1/ - here is my project at the beginning, when I create it, but when someone start in like this:

127.0.0.1/store - then it doesn't work, how to fix it and where do this? Somewhere in config?

Comment: you tried clearing the cache? and what kind of errors .. share it

Comment: What error screen you are getting? and  what about 'URL' in app.php file

Answer (score 0):

I think the setup is wrong, there are different ways to boot laravel on localhost 
1. Run the following command from the project root directory
`php artisan serve` then go to 127.0.0.1:8000 
`php artisan serve --port=8080` to change the port
2. Access it from localhost by 
`go to -> xampp(if you're using xampp) -> htdocs` 
mkdir (create a folder) "store" 
then cd into the folder, run the following command 
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel .` 
go to -> 127.0.0.1/store/public